# Select box returns ID as value not the name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Merry Christmas to you all. Hope we are all having a wonderful time? I'm sure my guess is right. Could someone help me out on this? I don't know why this code returns the id as the value when binding to a select box. All I want to do is to bind a record of MySQL DB to a select box. Though, it is smooth when not using a where clause,

This is the controller:

```
public function create()
    {
      $listCompanies = Company::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('companyname', 'desc')->lists('companyname', 'id')->toArray();
        return view('product.create')->with('listCompanies', $listCompanies);
    }
```

This is the view:

```
<p>{!! Form::select('companyname', array('' => 'Select a Company') + $listCompanies) !!} </p>
```

When I checked the returned source page I found this:

```
<p><select name="companyname"><option value="" selected="selected">Select a Company</option><option value="1">New Company Nigeria</option><option value="2">Latest Company Nigeria</option></select> </p>
```

When I select a value from the selectbox, it returns the id, ie, 1, and that is what it adds to the DB not the actual value.

See the attached image for clarification. Please, your input is highly needed.[image: It is suppose to return this but it doesn't]

[image: This is what it actually returns. The id of the company not the name]

Comment: Why don't you want to add the id? It looks like a foreign key to me?

Comment: The id should be there but the display should be the name of the company, since id is irrelevant to the end users to see.

Comment: The database should have the id. It's not meant to be seen by the user. You load the relationship with a query. I'm missing something in your question.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript? Is that what you mean by return value?

Comment: No JjavaScript. I'm working with Laravel.

Comment: Are you seeing a change between screens? Like the first load shows the select box as you expect and then after you click save it shows differently? Could it be using a different controller method the second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option value is what gets saved. If you just want the names, use `lists('companyName', 'companyName')`

But typically you do want the `id` in your foreign key field. How do you have the relationship set up?

Comment: Thanks, Zoe, I appreciate. This solved the issue. Thanks a bunch!!! Merry Christmas and happy new year in advance

Comment: How do I get the ID on the blade page into an hidden field?